# Times that respect clock-hand symmetry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, word-problem

A friend asked me for the time. When I looked at my analog clock (which only has a minute hand and an hour hand, no second hand), I thought of telling her the time with the hour and minute hands swapped, and then have her work out the actual time. Then I realized that not all clock-hand configurations make sense when the hands are swapped.

Let $T$ denote the set of all clock-hand configurations on an analog clock that occur over twelve hours.

**Question:** What is the subset of times $S\subseteq T$ such that when the hands are swapped, the time still makes sense? (In other words, $S$ is the maximal subset of $T$ closed under the operation of swapping the hands.)

*Comments:* $S\neq T$, since for example $3:00\notin S$. But $S$ is non-empty, since $12:00\in S$.

Comment: I am assuming that the clock has no *second* hand, only an *hour* hand and a *minute* hand.  Assuming so, have you done any work on the problem that you could share?

Comment: Thanks, I clarified the question. 
@JMoravitz: indeed, this is a repeat, I should probably close it! Thanks.